# What's the simplest way to add event listeners on Handlbar templates

Tags: javascript, dom-events, handlebars.js

Given the following code using Handlebars.js:

```
var templateString = "<div>{{{nameContainer}}}</div>";
var handlebarTemplate = handlebars.compile(templateString);
var context = {
   nameContainer: '<div id="myID">my name is John Doe</div>'
}

var html = handlebarTemplate(context);
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body') [0];
body.innerHTML = html;
```

What's the simplest way to add an event listener on `#myID` using Handlebars.js without the need to use something like `document.getElementById('myID').addEventListener(...)` after `html` is added to the DOM?

Comment: Sorry about that...the JSON object had the incorrect property name.

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with it but just wanted to know if there was any other way I could add an event handler while using handlebars. Maybe there's some sort of block-helpers or something.